# Update Nested Field in Cloud Firestore Using Dynamic Key and Auto Increment Swift

Tags: swift, dynamic, google-cloud-firestore, nested, google-cloud-functions

Taking the Firestore documentation as an example you can see that they have

```
{
    name: "Frank",
    favorites: { food: "Pizza", color: "Blue", height(cm): "100" },
    age: 12
}

// To update favorite color:
db.collection("users").doc("frank").update({
    "favorites.color": "Red"
})
```

Now If I wanted to auto increment the age this would be easy too using the documentation I can see and test that the following does work:

```
db.collection("users").doc("frank").updateData([
    "age": Fieldvalue.increment(Int64(1))])
```

I would like to know if there is a way to increment the height too with a dynamic key. So would like to do something like:

```
let updateKey = "favourites.height(cm)" 
db.collection("users").doc("frank").updateData([
    updateKey: FieldValue.increment(Int64(10))])


//which results in
{
    name: "Frank",
    favorites: { food: "Pizza", color: "Blue", height(cm): "110" },
    age: 12
}
```

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

[Firestore increment](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-increment) doesn't work on strings `favourites.height(cm)`. you need to change this field to number then use the increment feature. Otherwise it will just set this field to the value specified by the increment method